# Easygrid Custom formatter for creating link - not getting generated

Tags: grails, jqgrid, grails-plugin

I have created a page based on the examples found in the Easygrid petclinic sample apps.
Everything is working fine except the formatter/unformat.
I have a **field called 'key'** with label 'date', I am trying to generate hyperlink based on this field. I notice that the **generated page ignores this attribute**.

I am sharing the [controller and the gsp](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwYxA85P9A4maFB3MG5xdDJuZHM&usp=sharing)

Field key defined in controller as

```
        columns {
        key{ label 'Date'  }
```

In the View

```
    <div id="grid-container" style="max-height:100%;overflow:auto;">
     <grid:grid id='jqgridinitial' name="daily">
       <grid:set width="2000" height="450">
         <grid:set col="key" label="Date" formatter='f:customWikiFormat' unformat="f:wikiUnFormat"/>
```

The generated page is ignoring the formatter

```
   {"searchoptions":{"clearSearch":false},"editable":false,"name":"key","search":null,"sortable":true,"label":"Date"
```

},

I also referred [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219944/how-to-get-selected-row-values-in-easygrid) by the creator of the plugin

Please let me know, if any additional details are required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax a little wrong. Basically the parent tag is grid:grid and inside it you can set different properties ( by using grid:set ).
If you don't specify a 'col' then those properties will be set on the actual grid.

```
<grid:grid id='jqgridinitial' name="daily">
    <grid:set width="2000" height="450"/>
    <grid:set col="key" label="Date" width="100" formatter='f:customWikiFormat' unformat="f:wikiUnFormat"/>
</grid:grid>
```

Comment: THANK you. I got it working based on your explanation. FYI, the code you pasted looks same to me.

Comment: You didn't close the first grid:set in your sample